# Multiple instant apps for one application on play store

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

This is a short question.
Can we publish multiple instant apps of one application into play store and if yes, how does google play decide which one to run when we press "try it now"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have multiple instant modules on your application.

You will able to decide which one will be available on the "Try now" button at the **Google Play Console -> Release Management -> Android Instant Apps**.

Sources:

- [Android Developers - Multiple entry points](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/overview#multiple-entry-points)
- [Provide multiple entry points into an instant experience](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/guides/multiple-entry-points)